# eventlet hangs when using futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-2.7, monkeypatching, eventlet, concurrent.futures

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Server x64, Python 2.7.3, futures==2.1.5, eventlet==0.14.0

Did anybody hit the same problem?

```
import eventlet
import futures
import random

# eventlet.monkey_patch() # Uncomment this line and it will hang!

def test():
    if random.choice((True, False)):
        raise Exception()
    print "OK this time"

def done(f):
    print "done callback!"

def main():
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        fu = []
        for i in xrange(6):
            f = executor.submit(test)
            f.add_done_callback(done)
            fu.append(f)
        futures.wait(fu, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code, if you uncomment the line, will hang. I can only stop it by pressing Ctrl+C. In this case the following KeyboardInterrupt traceback is printed: https://gist.github.com/max-lobur/8526120#file-traceback

This works fine with ThreadPoolExecutor.

Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by setting os=True for monkey patching. The nature of this behaviour is still unclear, however, and needs some further research.

Comment: True, this really helps. But currently I'm not able to change patching strategy on the project. Also, I thought they're all True by default..

Comment: Nevermind, if you specify os=True, nothing else will get patched. :) I tried rather not patching thread and that worked.

Comment: Ok. Thread definitely should be patched, I think it's the only thing why we use eventlet :)

Comment: Eventlet was designed to solve the problem of writing code in callbacks. What good is eventlet+futures/callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

I think this KeyboardInterrupt reaches the started process because under ubuntu and most linux systems the new process is created with fork - starting a new process from the current one with the **same stdin** and stdout and stderr. So the KeyboardInterrupt can reach the **child process**. Maybe someone who know something more can add thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for your participation. I think my question wasn't very clear, sorry. I updated it to be more obvious